# Как открыть изображение в python?

Tags: python, изображения, url

Здравствуйте.
Возникла такая проблема, нужно открыть url картинку в **python 2.7** не скачивая файл и не через браузер. Это возможно?
Пытался сделать через библиотеку **kivy**, но там нечего не понятно и он почему то не может открыть jpg изображение. Через **PIL** тоже не выходит...

Comment: Добавьте описание того, что именно Вам не понятно и почему что-то не выходит.

Comment: Чтобы показать картинку вам её всё равно  придётся скачать (сохранять на диск не обязательно). Вот [пример кода](http://stackoverflow.com/a/32859290/4279). Старайтесь одну проблему за раз решать. Научитесь показывать локальную картинку в нужном формате. Когда эта часть работает, то попробуйте её же (эту же картинку по http-ссылке показать). Для тестов можете `python-m SimpleHTTPServer` команду в директории с картинкой запустить, чтобы сделать её доступной по http. Когда столкнётесь с конкретной проблемой, опубликуйте минимальный пример кода, который её показывает [mcve]

Answer (score -3):

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.image import AsyncImage
from kivy.lang import Builder


Builder.load_string('''
<CenteredAsyncImage>:
    size: self.texture_size
    size_hint: None, None
    pos_hint: {'center_x': 0.5, 'center_y': 0.5}
''')


class CenteredAsyncImage(AsyncImage):
    pass


class TestAsyncApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return CenteredAsyncImage(
            source='URL')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    TestAsyncApp().run()
```

А использовать Kivy только лишь для того, чтобы вывести изображение, все равно, что забивать гвозди микроскопом! Вы бы еще OpenCV попробовали...