# Как открыть картинку по ссылке в python

Tags: python, url, img

При отображении `jpg` при помощи `kivy`, почему то не может отобразить фото с форматом `jpg`. при этом `png` отображается отлично. Ошибка при `jpg` следующая:

```
[ERROR             ] [Loader      ] Failed to load image <http://images.national
geographic.com/wpf/media-live/photos/000/762/custom/panda-trees-woods-990-dl_762
56_990x557.jpg>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\kivy\loader.py", line 342, in _load_urllib

    data = self._load_local(_out_filename, kwargs)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\kivy\loader.py", line 277, in _load_local
    return ImageLoader.load(filename, keep_data=True, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\kivy\core\image\__init__.py", line 430, in
 load
    im = loader(filename, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\kivy\core\image\__init__.py", line 198, in
 __init__
    self._data = self.load(filename)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\kivy\core\image\img_pil.py", line 101, in
load
    return list(self._img_read(im))
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\kivy\core\image\img_pil.py", line 86, in _
img_read
    img_tmp.mode.lower(), img_tmp.tobytes())
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\PIL\Image.py", line 512, in __getattr__
    raise AttributeError(name)
AttributeError: tobytes
[Error 32] ╧ЁюЎхёё эх ьюцхЄ яюыєўшЄ№ фюёЄєя ъ Їрщыє,: 'c:\\users\\andrei\\appdat
a\\local\\temp\\kivyloaderag7jgt.jpe'
[INFO              ] [Base        ] Leaving application in progress...
```

Сам код вот.

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.image import AsyncImage
from kivy.lang import Builder


Builder.load_string('''
<CenteredAsyncImage>:
    size: self.texture_size
    size_hint: None, None
    pos_hint: {'center_x': 0.5, 'center_y': 0.5}
''')



class CenteredAsyncImage(AsyncImage):
    pass


class TestAsyncApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return CenteredAsyncImage(
            source='http://images.nationalgeographic.com/wpf/media-live/photos/000/762/custom/panda-trees-woods-990-dl_76256_990x557.jpg')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    TestAsyncApp().run()
```

Использовал эту статью. https://coderwall.com/p/lngdkg/saving-images-with-just-requests-http-for-humans .там вроде как сохраняется изображение, но как его отобразить я тоже не нашёл, ибо при отображении через print или попытке вывести через библиотеку GUI выходит либо ошибка либо это: `<PIL.JpegImagePlugin.JpegImageFile image mode=RGB size=1040x1280 at 0x29641C0>`

Нашёл ещё вот такой скрипт, нормального описания к нему нет и при этом он ещё и не работает, выводит эту ошибку: `seek` на строчке `im = Image.open(r.raw)`

Все остальные скрипты, которые я находил в интернете, это подобие описанных выше, только либо модифицированные либо упрощённые.

Comment: *"Нашёл вот такой скрипт"* прочтите [мой комментарий к вашему похожему вопросу, который вам дал ссылку на **рабочий** код с `Image.open()`](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/588153/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%be%d1%82%d0%ba%d1%80%d1%8b%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%b8%d0%b7%d0%be%d0%b1%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b6%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d0%b2-python#comment788688_588153). Он рекомендует одну проблему решать за раз. Если не получилось у вас `Image.open()` использовать, то задайте вопрос, я бы вам ответил, что ответ по ссылке явно упоминает требуемую версию Pillow (у вас вероятно старая версия).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Чтобы открыть картинку вам необходимо сначала ее скачать, а потом уже показывать.

Для того чтобы скачать изображение, можно воспользоваться библиотекой `urllib`, а для того чтобы показать изображение библиотекой 'PIL'.

Функция `print` вам бы точно не помогла, так как она используется для вывода текстовой информации в консоль, а не рисования изображений.

Вот простой пример:

```
from PIL import Image
from urllib.request import urlopen

url = "http://risovach.ru/upload/2014/02/mem/muzhik-bleat_43233947_orig_.jpg"

image = Image.open(urlopen(url))
image.show()
```