# urllib и python 2.7 или как изменить код под старую версию

Tags: python, urllib

Здравствуйте. нашёл скрипт, для отображения фото по ссылке в python.

```
from io import BytesIO
from PIL import Image
from urllib.request import urlopen

url = "http://risovach.ru/upload/2014/02/mem/muzhik-bleat_43233947_orig_.jpg"
req = urlopen(url)
print(req)
data = BytesIO()
data.write(req.readall())
image = Image.open(data)
image.show()
```

Но возникла такая проблема, что стандартная библиотека `from urllib.request import urlopen` у меня нет так как у меня версия python 2.7. Я поискал в интернете и там написано, что для версии 2.7 надо использовать `urllib2`. Но когда я использую `urllib2` то у меня выдаёт ошибку

```
<addinfourl at 41893280 whose fp = <socket._fileobject object at 0x027F07F0>>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\proj\git\PythonApplication2\PythonApplication2\module1.py", line 12,
in <module>
    data.write(req.readall())
AttributeError: addinfourl instance has no attribute 'readall'
```

Почитав в интернете, я не нашёл замены данной строки при использовании `urllib2` .Как решить данную проблему? или где скачать эту библиотеку `from urllib.request import urlopen` для python 2.7

Comment: если код не ваш, то приведите ссылку откуда вы его взяли.

Comment: связанный вопрос:  [Как открыть изображение в python?](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/588153/23044)

Answer (score 1):

В Python 2.7 нет метода `readall`, но его роль выполняет вызов `read()` без аргументов, поэтому, чтобы скрипт заработал, достаточно поменять `readall` на `read` и всё.

В Python 3 вызов `read()` без аргументов так же аналогичен вызову `readall()`, поэтому можно пойти дальше и написать скрипт, который будет работать в обоих версиях питона (в первой строке [shebang](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A8%D0%B5%D0%B1%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B3_(Unix)) для *nix-систем):

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

from __future__ import unicode_literals, print_function

import sys
from io import BytesIO

from PIL import Image

if sys.version_info.major == 2:
    import urllib2 as urequest  # Python 2.x
else:
    import urllib.request as urequest  # Python 3.x


url = "http://risovach.ru/upload/2014/02/mem/muzhik-bleat_43233947_orig_.jpg"
req = urequest.urlopen(url)
print(req)
data = BytesIO()
data.write(req.read())
image = Image.open(data)
image.show()
```

Но при доработке этого скрипта нужно не забывать, что `urequest` в Python 2 и `urequest` в Python 3 — объекты хоть и похожие, но разные, и между ними есть ещё много мелких и не очень различий. Возможно, лучше даже будет просто взять [requests](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/requests) и не заморачиваться.

Comment: к слову:  [`Image.open(urlopen(url))` работает и так недавних версиях Pillow](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/589668/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%be%d1%82%d0%ba%d1%80%d1%8b%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%ba%d0%b0%d1%80%d1%82%d0%b8%d0%bd%d0%ba%d1%83-%d0%bf%d0%be-%d1%81%d1%81%d1%8b%d0%bb%d0%ba%d0%b5-%d0%b2-python#comment790689_589668)

Comment: @jfs видимо, заработало совсем-совсем недавно, ибо ещё пару месяцев назад он мне жаловался на отсутствующий seek

Comment: пройдите по ссылкам, ответ *явно* говорит с какой версии это работает (2.8 вышла в апреле 2015—больше чем пару месяцев назад)

Comment: @jfs ссылка здесь всего одна, и никаких упоминаний версий по ней не вижу ¯\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: Попробуйте следовать "по ссылкам" (множественное число—два клика) пока не увидите явное упоминание. Если не справитесь, пишите я явную ссылку на ответ дам (один клик).

Comment: @jfs таки аж целых три клика, это как бы уже перебор) Впрочем, таки работает и видимо я что-то напутал, так что ладно.

Comment: два клика, если на ссылку по вопросом нажать наверху (про ссылку в комментарии к этому ответу я уже забыл—и не увидел в интерфейсе в телефоне)